# Is it correct to assign HttpContext.Current inside a task factory?

Tags: c#

I was getting HttpContext.Current as null inside the method which is called inside a task factory. So I assigned the HttpContext.Current to currentContext variable. Then I used the same variable to assign HttpContext.Current.

```
    var currentContext = HttpContext.Current;
    Task shipmentCreationCompleted = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        HttpContext.Current = currentContext;
        MethodToPerformSomeAction();
    });
```

It is now working fine without any problem. Please let me know if my code has any problem technically. Or is there any alternate way to handle this problem?

Comment: Pass HttpContext to the task factory as a parameter, then you will always be using the same HttpContext as the calling method

Comment: Thank you alikuli. What difference does it make if I use that?

Comment: You will be using the exact same reference of the request that the calling task is using. No incompatibility. Basically this is Parameter Injection.

Since your method works, possibly that method is good too, but so many things happen in multi user environments, that I feel safer to pass the reference of the HttpContext and use it. this way I always KNOW the animal I am dealing with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally i used like this based on the comment,

```
Task shipmentCreationCompleted = Task.Factory.StartNew(currentContext =>
    {
        HttpContext.Current = (HttpContext)currentContext;
        MethodToPerformSomeAction();
    }, HttpContext.Current);
```

It works great!